# Twisted - CRITICAL - Unhandled error in Deferred... no stack trace

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, twisted

Using Scrapy for web crawling and I've run into this issue all of a sudden, this is the only result I get from the stack trace:

```
2017-10-31 14:15:24,980 - twisted - CRITICAL - Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

With nothing after that.

The spider is being called from a separate python script with

```
process.crawl(IndexSpiderSingle)
process.start()
```

And according to logs I've put throughout the spider's `__init__()` function, it instantiates without issue. It seems to encounter the issue *after* instantiation and before going onto call the `start_requests()` function, as no logs from the next method even get called.

Currently pulling my hair out, any help is appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a version of Twisted which has https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8860 or https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/7927 unfixed.  Try upgrading Twisted to get the traceback reported in the log.

Comment: Apologies for late response. Still getting the same issue, unfortunately, even with the latest version of Twisted.

Comment: Note that #7927 is not yet fixed in any version of Twisted :(  You might want to read the details there and try to determine if this is what's affecting you.  Or post an http://sscce.org/ and someone else can try to determine it for you.